# loop through sheet for unmarked value to update Google contacts

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, range

I've got a working script that grabs the last row of a Google sheet and pushes the info into Google contacts.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  //var emailRow = ss.getRange('F2:F').getValues(); 
var emailRowNum = ss.getLastRow();   //var emailRowNum = emailRow.filter(String).length + 1;

function email() {
  var emailNew = ss.getRange(emailRowNum,6).getValue();   //var emailNew = ss.getRange("F"+emailRowNum).getValues();
  return emailNew;}

function givenName() {
  var fname = ss.getRange(emailRowNum,4).getValue();
  return fname;}

function lastName() {
  var lname = ss.getRange(emailRowNum,5).getValue();
  return lname;}

function loc() {
  var street = ss.getRange(emailRowNum,8).getValue();
  var city =  ss.getRange(emailRowNum,9).getValue();
  return street + " " + city;}

function phone() {
  var phone = ss.getRange(emailRowNum,7).getValue();
  return phone;}

function notes() {
  var date = ss.getRange(emailRowNum,1).getValue();
  var work = ss.getRange(emailRowNum,2).getValue();
  var photo = ss.getRange(emailRowNum,3).getValue();
  var site = ss.getRange(emailRowNum,12).getValue();
  var find = ss.getRange(emailRowNum,10).getValue();
  var referrer = ss.getRange(emailRowNum,11).getValue();
  return (date + "\n\n" + work + "\n\n" + photo + "\n\n" + site + "\n\n" + find + " " + referrer + "\n\n-- eom --\n\n");}


function create() {
  var fname = givenName();
  var lname = lastName();
  var contact = ContactsApp.createContact(fname, lname, email());

  var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('emf');
  group.addContact(contact);

  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByName(fname + ' ' + lname);
  var setaddress = contacts[0].addAddress(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_ADDRESS,loc());
  var setphone = contacts[0].addPhone(ContactsApp.Field.MAIN_PHONE,phone());
  for (var i in contacts) {
    contacts[i].setNotes(notes());
  }
}
```

I'd like to modify it so that instead of grabbing the last row, it checks a column for a (not) value. If value is not found, then update Google contacts with that row's information.

Currently, I'm getting a 'Range not found' error ...

```
function info(){ 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = ss.getRange("N1:N").getValues(); 
  for(var n=0;n<data.length;n++){
    if(data[n-1] != 'done'){
      var email = ss.getRange("F"+n).getValue(); // Range not found error
      var fname = ss.getRange("D"+n).getValue();
      var lname = ss.getRange("E"+n).getValue();
      var city = ss.getRange("I"+n).getValue();
      var street = ss.getRange("H"+n).getValue();
      var phone = ss.getRange("G"+n).getValue();
      var date = ss.getRange("A"+n).getValue();
      var work = ss.getRange("B"+n).getValue();
      var photo = ss.getRange("C"+n).getValue();
      var site = ss.getRange("L"+n).getValue();
      var find = ss.getRange("J"+n).getValue();
      var referrer = ss.getRange("K"+n).getValue();

      var contact = ContactsApp.createContact(fname, lname, email);
      var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('emf');
      group.addContact(contact);

      var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByName(fname + ' ' + lname);
      var setaddress = contacts[0].addAddress(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_ADDRESS,street + " " + city);
      var setphone = contacts[0].addPhone(ContactsApp.Field.MAIN_PHONE,phone);
      for (var i in contacts) {
        contacts[i].setNotes(date + "\n\n" + work + "\n\n" + photo + "\n\n" + site + "\n\n" + find + " " + referrer + "\n\n-- eom --\n\n");}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`1` is the first row using A1Notation with `getRange()`. The first iteration is trying to `getValue()` of `F0`. Changing the `n` to start at `1` and `n <= data.length` should get the ranges you are looking for.

```
...

for(var n=1;n<=data.length;n++){
  if(data[n-1] == 'done'){
    var email = ss.getRange("F"+n).getValue(); // Range not found error

...
```

**edit:** One thing to note the `var data = ss.getRange("N1:N").getValues();` range is going to loop over all 1000 default rows. This may not be ideal if your data set is significantly smaller than 1000 rows.

Comment: Ok thanks. Incrementing the start and end loop points fixed the Range error. Now I'm getting a "Service error: ContactsApp: [Line 1, Column 384, element gd:givenName] Missing required text content (line 71, file "contact")" on the `var contact = ContactsApp.createContact(fname, lname, email);` line

Comment: That is because the value for `fname` is empty. Noticed i had deleted the `-1` in `data[n-1]` and was reading the incorrect row. As long as the row with `done` is populated, the correct values should now be set for `fname, lname, email`

Comment: --note: `var data = ss.getRange("N1:N").getValues()` + `if(data[n-1] != 'done'){}` means that any of the 1000 rows that do not have `done` in that column will be read and will have to have a value for `fname` etc. Is this intended behavior?

Comment: **updated code**: `if (data[n-1] == 'done') {}`. The computer reads the literal value `'done'`. It has no idea what `done` means, just if `done` is the value or not.